# Страна и государство

Tags: грамотная-речь

Не так давно в одной книге мне попалось утверждение, что современную Россию (и еще большую часть стран) называть государством не верно, потому что государство — это страна, если есть государь, то есть монархия. Таким образом, например, Испания, Великобритания, Япония или Нидерланды — это государства, а вот Россия или, скажем, Китай — это страны.
Мне бы хотелось знать, грамотно ли употреблять термин "государство" по отношению к стране, в которой нет монархии?

Comment: Россия - страна, РФ - государство с Государственной Думой, Государственным гимном, Государственным флагом, даже - ГИБДД

Answer (score 2):

Хотя понятия страна и государство часто используются как синонимичные, между ними имеется существенная разница.

Понятие «государство» обозначает политическую систему власти, установленную на определённой территории, особого рода организацию, в то время как понятие «страна» скорее относится к культурным, общегеографическим (общность территории) и другим факторам. Термин «страна» также имеет менее официальную окраску. Похожее различие существует и в английском языке со словами country (которое ближе к понятию страна) и state (государство), хотя в определённом контексте они могут выступать как взаимозаменяемые.

Следует сказать и о  самом понятии "государство". В современном значении оно возникло лишь в начале XVI в. В науку его ввел итальянский мыслитель Никколо Макиавелли (1469-1527). Он использовал для обозначения государства слово stato (от лат. status - положение, статус). До этого все государственные образования обозначались различными терминами: "республика", "городская община", "княжеское господство", "земля", "полис", "единовластное правление", "тирания", "олигархия" и т.п. Теперь все эти государственные образования обозначались одним термином.

В отличие от английского, русский язык не заимствовал латинское слово или его западноевропейские эквиваленты для обозначения феномена state. Латинское слово status было использовано только для обозначения социального положения человека, в то время как фонетическая калька немецкого слова Staat стала обозначать административную единицу внутри федерального государства, как, например, в выражении «Соединенные Штаты». Слово «государство» является производным от слова «государь», которое обозначало либо хозяина феодального владения, владельца холопов, либо верховного правителя и которое часто являлось русским эквивалентом латинского слова dominus. Ричард Пайпс даже настаивал на том, что слово «государство» более адекватно может быть переведено на английский не как state, а как domain, наверное, в смысле «господское владение».

Таким образом, история понятия «государство» представляется на первый взгляд однозначной. Древнерусское слово «господарь», или «осподарь», этимологически связанное с однокоренными словами «господь» и «господин», первоначально означало «хозяин, владелец холопов и домашнего хозяйства», а родственное с ним церковнославянское слово «господа» означало «домашнее хозяйство или земельное владение». В этом смысле слово «господарь» присутствует уже на новгородской берестяной грамоте XI века и в Синайском Патерике XI—XII веков. Несколько позднее слово «господарь» стало использоваться и в политическом смысле, поскольку стало официальным титулом князей. Это произошло благодаря влиянию латинского языка на канцелярский язык тех русских князей, чьи княжества вошли в состав Королевства Польского и Литвы. Первое неоспоримо политическое использование термина «господарь» относится к 1349 году, когда славянская версия титулатуры Казимира III, короля польского, называет его «и господарь руское земле», что одновременно передавалось по-латыни как dominusque terre Russiae.

Так что термин этот наш родной, у нас именно **государство**, а живём мы в **стране**.

Comment: В том смысле, что государство - политическая система власти.Государство можно определить как особую форму организации политической власти в обществе страны, наделенной суверенитетом,где власть осуществляет управление обществом на основе права с помощью специального механизма (аппарата). Сущность государства может выражаться в осуществлении интересов либо большинства, либо отдельных социальных групп.

Answer (score 0):

Если обратиться к данным Википедии, то увидим, что форма государственного правления является не только монархической, но и республиканской. Сюда входит:

> - Парламентская;
> - Президентская;
> - Смешанная;
>
> ***Отсюда следует, что такое утверждение ошибочно. Подробнее здесь:***[Государство - Википедия](http://www.quickiwiki.com/ru/%C3%EE%F1%F3%E4%E0%F0%F1%F2%E2%EE)

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Страна

Еще различие страны и государства можно увидеть
в словарях:  страна - это край, земля, народ, отчизна, родина.
Государство - это статус, состояние, держава, скипетр, стан, власть, панство.

Кстати, в албанском страна - VEND!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Только дилетант мог бы уцепиться за мнимый довод и затем из пальца высосать новый тезис. В данном случае автор такого утверждения подвёл этимологию к семантике, перепутал их, и, как результат, подменил одно понятие другим. Профессионал бы такую ошибку вряд ли допустил.

"Употреблять термин "государство" по отношению страны, в которой нет монархии" вполне уместно и грамотно, так как в современном языке слово "государство" имеет один смысл - это территориально-политическое объединение и от структуры управления или же строя он не зависит.

Answer (score 0):

Всплыл этот старый вопрос - удивительно, что никто так и не дал внятного ответа по сути спрашиваемого.

> Мне бы хотелось знать, грамотно ли употреблять термин "государство" по
>   отношению страны, в которой нет монархии?

Вполне грамотно. Государство - понятие общественно-политическое, Страна - географическое.

Комментировать цитату из неназванной книги я не буду, ясно, что автор или абсолютно не разбирается в вопросе, или банально эпатирует публику. Тут интереснее другое, почему "государство" давно и прочно потеряло связь с государем.

Само это слово "государь" является не чем иным как стяжением исторического "господарь" - и в русском употреблении вплоть да XVIII-XIX вообще не было связано исключительно с монархом, верховным правителем. Ничего удивительного, что и "государство" не было связано с конкретной формой правления. Причем этот факт прослеживается с самого начала употребления слова - так, исторические государственные образования (от египтян и греков) именовались государствами без всякой отсылки к верховному правителю.  Признаки государства - совсем другие...

Что же касается слово "страна", то оно употребляется (не совсем, кстати, корректно) лишь по отношению к географической составляющей государства, его границам. Или вообще без связи с государством ("горная страна" - это просто ландшафт).